# Creating a INSERT TRIGGER in different table

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle11g

I need help on creating a trigger on my table1
that will insert specific columns into table2 from table1.
How can i do that? I am using Oracle 11G XE .

Here is my code:

```
create trigger AllowanceTrigger
on ex_bulacan
after insert
as
insert into allowance VALUES (PLANT_ORIGIN,SO_NO, SO_STATUS,SO_REMARKS,DRIVER_NAME)
    select plant_origin, sales_order_no, status,remarks, driver_name
    from ex_bulacan;
go ;
```

When I run that command I get this error

```
ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword
```

The explanation is:

> ORA-04071. 00000 -  "missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword"
>   *Cause:    The trigger statement is missing the BEFORE/AFTER/INSTEAD OF clause.
>   *Action:   Specify either BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF.

Comment: A good site to check out is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm

Comment: BY THE WAY HERE IS MY STATEMENT FOR THAT, IM USING SQL DEVELOPER      create trigger AllowanceTrigger
on ex_bulacan
after insert  
as
insert into allowance VAALUES (PLANT_ORIGIN,SO_NO, SO_STATUS,SO_REMARKS,DRIVER_NAME)
    select plant_origin, sales_order_no, status,remarks, driver_name
    from ex_bulacan;
go ;

Comment: Well, VAALUES should be VALUES. Please add that info to the original question as well.

Comment: This is a syntax error.  What you should do is read the documenation (Amil has provided a link) and spot where your code varies from it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "go" statement in PL/SQL, and you have not followed the correct syntax for a trigger definition (it is [well documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374))

Try this:

```
create trigger AllowanceTrigger
after insert on ex_bulacan
begin
    insert into allowance (PLANT_ORIGIN,SO_NO, SO_STATUS,SO_REMARKS,DRIVER_NAME)
        select plant_origin, sales_order_no, status,remarks, driver_name
        from ex_bulacan;
end;
```

I'm not sure whether it does what you intended.  It fires once per insert **statement**, not for each row, and it inserts **all** rows from ex_bulacan into allowance, not just the ones you just inserted.  Maybe what you want is actually:

```
create trigger AllowanceTrigger
after insert on ex_bulacan
for each row
begin
    insert into allowance (PLANT_ORIGIN,SO_NO, SO_STATUS,SO_REMARKS,DRIVER_NAME)
        values (:new.plant_origin, :new.sales_order_no, :new.status, :new.remarks, 
                :new.driver_name);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your respond.. im gonna try your code.. i wanna ask what if i want not just the insert but also the update on that specific data?

Comment: Its working!! Thanks you so much.. i wanna know how to compile your code with update command?

Comment: You can perform an update in a trigger like this: **update allowance set status = :new.status where so_no = :new.sales_order_no;**

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code. You must specify the trigger in this order:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AllowanceTrigger
AFTER INSERT
ON ex_bulacan
```